# Specify retention of 'x versions' of a delta table?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

VACUUM will remove Delta table data files that are no longer in the latest state of the transaction log for the table and are older than a retention threshold. That retention threshold can be specified explicitly during the VACUUM operation `VACUUM table_name [RETAIN num HOURS]` or implicitly via the table property `delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration = 'interval X days'`. However, it appears to only be possible to specify that threshold in time. I'd like to guarantee retention of at least x versions of a delta table. Is there a workaround to enable this? Perhaps without synchronizing VACUUM and write operations? I'd like to VACUUM the table on a schedule. But the table can be written to at random times. Say I have `delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration = 'interval 7 days'`, the table has not been written to for over a week, and then a scheduled background process runs VACUUM; then only the latest version of the table will remain, right? Behavior like this would not be desired in my case. We'd at the very least like to guarantee at least 2 versions.

Comment: Not a direct answer but if your really need to keep actual versions use the change data feed and create an SCD table that you can control.  You could schedule a job to copy all changes every two days (assuming your 7 days) and be safe.  Per https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#-data-retention and https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/255 this is the only way to guarantee versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the necessary retention hours for the last X versions by examining the Delta log and then use it in the `VACUUM` command.
Below is a PySpark version to calculate it.

```py
from delta import DeltaTable
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

path = 'path_to_your_table'
delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path)
history = delta_table.history(10)  # set the number of required versions here

diff_to_now = F.current_timestamp() - F.col('timestamp')
necessary_retention = F.ceil(diff_to_now.cast(T.LongType()) / F.lit(3600))
cols = [
    F.col('version').alias('version'),
    F.col('timestamp').alias('timestamp'),
    diff_to_now.alias('diff_to_now'),
    necessary_retention.alias('necessary_retention_hours')
]
history_2 = history.select(cols)
history_2.show(10, False)

# +-------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
# |version|timestamp          |diff_to_now                               |necessary_retention_hours|
# +-------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
# |578    |2024-02-08 10:16:58|INTERVAL '0 00:02:49.869462' DAY TO SECOND|1                        |
# |577    |2024-02-08 10:10:30|INTERVAL '0 00:09:17.869462' DAY TO SECOND|1                        |
# |576    |2024-02-08 09:44:03|INTERVAL '0 00:35:44.869462' DAY TO SECOND|1                        |
# |575    |2024-02-08 09:36:48|INTERVAL '0 00:42:59.869462' DAY TO SECOND|1                        |
# |574    |2024-02-08 09:29:20|INTERVAL '0 00:50:27.869462' DAY TO SECOND|1                        |
# |573    |2024-02-08 09:22:52|INTERVAL '0 00:56:55.869462' DAY TO SECOND|1                        |
# |572    |2024-02-08 09:17:31|INTERVAL '0 01:02:16.869462' DAY TO SECOND|2                        |
# |571    |2024-02-08 09:05:52|INTERVAL '0 01:13:55.869462' DAY TO SECOND|2                        |
# |570    |2024-02-08 08:56:58|INTERVAL '0 01:22:49.869462' DAY TO SECOND|2                        |
# |569    |2024-02-08 08:49:09|INTERVAL '0 01:30:38.869462' DAY TO SECOND|2                        |
# +-------+-------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------+

retention_df = history_2.select(
    F.min_by('necessary_retention_hours', 'version').alias('retention')
)
retention = retention_df.collect()[0]['retention']
print(retention)
# >>> 2
```

Comment: Thanks this approach will definitely work, although some of the syntax I couldn't verify with my pyspark version. Somewhat outside the scope of my original question, but is there also any way to ensure the delta_log also can retain 'X version'?

Comment: I've tested the code with `pyspark==3.4.1,delta-spark==2.4.0`. I am not aware of such [table property](https://docs.delta.io/latest/table-properties.html) that can specify "Retain at least X versions".